# Appending a string to the first element in a list

Tags: ansible

I have a list of items.

```yaml
my_list: ["item", "otheritem"]
```

I'm using this list like so, in a task:

```yaml
- name: Input to script
  command: >-
    ./myscript.sh --issue -d {{ my_list | join(" -i ") }}
  args:
    chdir: "~/.bin"
```

Since the list will be populated by user configuration, I would like to manipulate the first item in the list programmatically before my task executes.

How can I append a string to the first item in the list before joining them, and effectively change:

```yaml
my_list: ["item", "otheritem"]
```

to

```yaml
my_list: ["item my appended", "otheritem"]
```

before the `join()` in my task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice the list and rebuild a new one:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    my_new_list: "{{ [my_list[0] + ' my appended'] + my_list[1:] }}"
```